# Prove/disprove that if R and S are transitive then R union S is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

The problem reads:

Let R and S be relations on a set A. If R and S are transitive then R$U$S is transitive.

I know from a homework problem that R$U$S is not transitive, but I do not know why.

Wouldn't R$U$S be:
$\forall$ x,y,z $\in$ A (((xRy ^ yRz) v (xSy ^ ySz)) $\rightarrow$ R$U$S is transitive.

But what if there were some (x,y) $\in$ R and (y,z) $\in$ S such that x does not relate to z $\in$ R$U$S?

Am I on the right track?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Counterexample:
Let R {(1,2)} and S {(2,3)}. Then R and S are transitive but R$U$S is not.

Comment: Let $A=\Bbb N$. Let $(u,v)\in R$ iff $u<v$. Let $(u,v)\in S$ iff $v<u.$ Let $x=z=1$ and $y=2.$ Then ($x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ belong to $R\cup S$ but $(x,z)=(1,1)\not \in R\cup S.$

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

$R=\{(1,2)\}$

$S=\{(2,1)\}$

$R$ and $S$ are both transitive, but $R \cup S=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is not

Comment: Thank you. I used R={(1,2)} and S={(2,3)} -- is that valid?. Also, wouldn't {(1,2),(2,1)} be transitive because 1R2 and 2R1? Or is it not because there is no (1,1)?

Comment: @McSpeenies yes, That one works as well. In fact, I thought about using that one as well, but figured that by using the same elements in both relations, you can have both relations defined over the same set, which I feel makes it a little 'cleaner' as a counterexample. But yours works just fine!